# MyPy linting conflicting typing with typing.Self

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

During linting and rewriting of an immutable class, operations do not pass the mypy checker.
The class implements operations such as`__add__`, however, every function that returns a new instance of the same class triggers a typing error `Incompatible return value type (got "Point", expected "Self")  [return-value]mypy(error)`

Methods I've tried:

- `T = TypeVar("T", bound="A")` As the parameter T was bound to A, mypy would recognize instancing A() as a subclass of T
- `class A(Generic[T])` ditto
- `return cast(T, A())` This works, but requires casts to be scattered throughout the code.
- Above with ClassVar instead of Generic

Is there a solution that doesn't rely heavily on cast()?

### Minimal Reproducible example

```
from typing import Self
class A():
    def meth(self, other:Self) -> Self:
        return A()
```

Comment: I *believe* the issue here is that you are always returning the type `A`. Try `type(self)()`. Otherwise, just annotate it as returning `-> A:`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Please make this an answer so I can accept. I'll be disabling mypy, as it removes all benefits of python over any other language.

Comment: I mean, it's *finding a real error*. If you did `class B(A)` then your annotation implied that `B().method(B())` would return an instane of `B`, but it would return an instance of `A()`

Comment: A tool can only go so far, if the person using it can't understand it, and becomes frustrated at his efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution to your problem is:

```
class A:
    def meth(self, other: "A") -> "A":
        return A()
```

I believe the problem with using `Self` here is that it incorrectly implies that the return type is based on the type of `self`, but it isn't, because you've hard-coded `A()`.

The other solution is:

```
class A:
    def meth(self, other: Self) -> Self:
        return type(self)()
```